# Sencha touch charts 2.0 beta : Blurring labels in IPhone device

Tags: extjs, charts, sencha-touch-2

We have developed an application in Sencha touch 2.1 . 
We need to display our records in  Column chart, so we used Sencha touch charts 2.0 beta .
It works well in Chrome, Safari browsers and android emulator. 
But in Iphone device the chart seems blurred . We cannot even read the labels in charts.

Comment: Is the image fully rendered? Because the Iphone sometimes shows the image blurred and after a while it gets sharpened.

Comment: Ya a1rpun canvas image fully rendered but we cannot even read the text (label of chart and axes) in canvas image